# How do I create and access Cassandra tables and keyspaces with double quotes in the name?

Tags: cassandra, escaping, cqlsh

For whatever reason, at work, a keyspace has been created in Cassandra with quotes around the name like this:

```
cqlsh:system> describe keyspaces

system_virtual_schema  system_auth   system              system_traces
system_schema          system_views  system_distributed  "keyspacewithquotes"
```

When I try to switch to that keyspace in `cqlsh` I get issues with the name.

I'm trying to replicate this situation at home:

```
cqlsh:system> CREATE  KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS '\"mykeyspace\"' 
      ...    WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:31 no viable alternative at input '\"mykeyspace\"' (CREATE  KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS ['\"mykeyspace\]...)">
```

I'm fairly sure I could do this on the command line outside `cqlsh` by passing escaped chars to the command line there. But what I want to do is query the tables inside this keyspace inside `cqlsh`.

My question is: **How to create and access Cassandra tables and keyspaces with double-quotes in the name?**

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, keyspace names are restricted to alphanumeric characters and underscores (`_`), but only alphanumeric characters are supported as the first character.

Mixed case names which are not quoted are forced into lowercase. The mixed case is preserved for names enclosed in double quotes. For example:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE "CamelCaseKS"
  WITH replication = {
    'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'us-west1': '3'
  };
```

To use a mixed case keyspace, enclose the name in double quotes. For example:

```
USE "CamelCaseKS";
```

Although there is nothing wrong with using mixed case names, we recommend using names in lowercase for simplicity. Cheers!